# Deserialization / model binding in MVC4 webapi does not work with arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, xmlserializer, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the new WebApi which is part of MVC4 beta. I have the following class:

```
public class Voucher
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string TableId { get; set; }
    public Product[] Products { get; set; } 
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public class VouchersController : ApiController
{
    public Voucher PostVoucher(Voucher voucher)
    {
          //....
    }
}
```

On the client side I serialize the data using an `XmlSerializer`. The output looks like expected and the `Products` array is serialized. If I post the data and put a break point inside the `PostVoucher` method, I get the data for `Id` and `TableId`, but `Products` is `null`. Any hint what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Just a question, have you added Serializable attribute in both classes (Voucher and Product)?

Comment: You don't need the `[Serializable]` attribute, classes without any attributes (i.e., POCO) work out fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an issue with the model binding / deserialization of complex types and XML in the ASP.NET Web API Beta. One way to solve this issue is to "disable" model binding, and select the "deserialization path" for this action. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/27/disabling-model-binding-on-asp-net-web-apis-beta.aspx shows how to do that.

Notice that this is a known issue for beta, and will be fixed in the next (RC) release.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I was tearing my hair out trying to work out why my action was happy to accept JSON but failed to deserialise XML.