# MVC4 not binding a list of basic types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I cannot, for the life of me, get this data to bind. Here's my JavaScript:

```
var params = { 'InvItemIDs': ["188475", "188490"]};
$.post("api/Orders/OrderFromInventory?" + $.param(params))
```

and the Controller action:

```
public HttpResponseMessage OrderFromInventory(IList<int> InvItemIDs)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage();
}
```

I've built the query string so that it's sending:

```
?InvItemIDs=188475&InvItemIDs=188490
```

as well as

```
?InvItemIDs[]=188475&InvItemIDs[]=188490
```

and even

```
?InvItemIDs[0]=188475&InvItemIDs[1]=188490
```

and none of them are binding. `InvItemIDs` is always `null`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

So it turns out all this is a bug (or something) in the new Web API controller code in MVC4. As soon as I moved the exact same code over to a standard controller it started working.

I'm still interested if anyone has any insight as to why the Web API would break this binding.

Comment: Not sure about that last edit there - wont putting spaces into the query string break it? If it doesn't, I presume it'll convert the spaces to %20 :)

Comment: Can I ask why you're using a List of ints rather than an array? or better yet, a params int array? Are you trying to retrieve data or send an order request to your controller?

Comment: I'm sending a POST to create an order from a set of inventory items. I'm not sure what you mean by "params int array".

Comment: You need to set the "traditional: true" in Ajax post for the array to work. I've updated my answer, give that a try.

Comment: Apparently the Web API uses a different model binder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9910490/1505426. It seems that there have been issues: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9592838/1505426

Comment: Please post the JSON sent to the server using Fiddler or similar.

Comment: I'm just posting text data: InvItemIDs=80075&InvItemIDs=880090 is my current test case. This works fine when posted to a System.Web.Http.Controller, but fails when posted to a System.Web.Http.ApiController.

Comment: WEB api default routing logic is different to ASP.net routing. They are base on the HTTP verbs, like "post, get, put, delete". Have tried my approach using post with HttpPost on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are using [HttpPost] where it will be expecting the data to be posted in "post body" instead of URL.

You can either

```
1, remove httpPost
2. put the list in the post content
```

You would need to set the "traditional: true" for the array to work. Here is a sample code that I've tested on my local project, give that a try

```
var InvItemIDs = ["188475", "188490"];
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
    url: "Home/TestIndex",
    datatype: "json",
    traditional: true,
    data:
    {
        'InvItemIDs': InvItemIDs
    }              
});
```

Comment: That's a good catch... unfortunately, it wasn't working before I added the HttpPost (that was part of my "what the hell is going on here?" process) and still doesn't work when I remove it.

Comment: It also doesn't work if I keep the post and submit the list as data.

Comment: I presumed the ajax command wasn't an issue? ie - if you enter the url with the query string directly it still fails?

Comment: It will fail because it has [HttpPost] attribute applied which means it will only accept Post request. And enter url on browser(i assume that's what you are referring to) is a Get request. I've test my post request by removing the "traditional:true" attribute and result is what admanb have seen

Comment: @Jack - admanb mentioned that `HttpPost` originally wasn't there and he only added it when trying to get it to work. I assumed from the question (as various querystring's were provided) that if it was removed (or changed to `HttpGet`) then the issue still occurred. Testing directly with `HttpGet` and a URL with a querystring can help to isolate where the actual issue is.

Answer (score 1):

This [Haacked blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) may help. Specifically, looking at his first example, what happens if you change `IList` to `ICollection`?

Something like this "should" work

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage OrderFromInventory(IList<int> InvItemIDs)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage();
}
```

with the querystring

```
?InvItemIDs=188475&InvItemIDs=188490
```

Comment: I wish it did, but I've read through that a dozen times. I've used both the basic notation and the [0]=,[1]= notation and none of them are binding.

Comment: Changing IList to ICollection also has no effect. Nor does changing it to List.

Comment: Hang on - is your parameter `InvItemIDs` (plural), and you're sending `InvItemID` (singular)?

Comment: God I wish. Sadly I just typed those in wrong. I'm definitely sending InvItemIDs.

Comment: I've just create a new MVC3 application (don't have MVC4 here - running "ahem" XP), added `IList<int> InvItemIDs` to the `About` action in the `HomeController` and called it via `http://localhost/Home/About?InvItemIDs=188475&InvItemIDs=188490`. This worked fine, so either its a MVC4 feature or you've done something like change the routes, default model binder, etc.